# Evaluate the integral $\int_{-1}^1 x \ln \frac{x}{1-e^{-a x}} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> How would you evaluate this definite integral with a combination of logarithmic and exponential functions:
>
> $$I(a)=\int_{-1}^1 x \ln \frac{x}{1-e^{-a x}} dx, \qquad a \geq 0$$

Mathematica didin't solve it for the general case.

My solution is hidden below (spoiler tag doesn't work properly for multiple lines for some reason).

Substitute $x=-t$:

$$I(a)=\int_{-1}^1 t \ln \frac{e^{a t}-1}{t} dt$$

> $$2 I(a)=\int_{-1}^1 x \ln \frac{e^{a x}-1}{1-e^{-a x}} dx=a \int_{-1}^1 x^2 dx+\int_{-1}^1 x \ln 1 dx=\frac{2a}{3}$$

The answer is:

$$I(a)=\frac{a}{3}$$

That's not how I actually found this solution though.

But how would you, at a first glance, attempt to solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Symmetry is the key. Let $f_a(x)=x \log\frac{x}{1-e^{-a x}}$. We may notice that

$$ f_a(-x) = -x \log \frac{x}{e^{ax}-1} = -x\log\frac{x}{1-e^{-ax}}-x\log\frac{1}{e^{ax}}=-f_a(x)+ax^2 \tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1}f_a(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\left(f_a(x)+f_a(-x)\right)\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}ax^2\,dx =\color{red}{\frac{a}{3}}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: I'll open my own solution then, there is no point in hiding it now

Comment: @YuriyS: I agree.

Comment: where do I go to learn how to integrate like you guys???

Comment: @qbert: here on MSE, it is the best place for learning integration techniques and various tricks.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll keep watching the integration tag with my popcorn then :)

Answer (score 1):

A slight generalisation $(q>0,n\in\mathbb{N})$. Let us denote

$$\
I_{q,n}(a)=\int_{-q}^qdxx^{2n-1}\log\left(\frac{x}{1-e^{-ax}}\right)
$$
Now differentiate w.r.t $a$. We get

$$
I_{q,n}'(a)=\int_{-q}^{q}dx\frac{x^{2n}}{1-e^{ax}}=\int_{0}^{q}dx\frac{x^{2n}}{1-e^{ax}}+\int_{-q}^{0}dx\frac{x^{2n}}{1-e^{ax}}=\\
=\int_{0}^{q}dx\frac{x^{2n}}{1-e^{ax}}+\int_{0}^{q}dx\frac{x^{2n}}{1-e^{-ax}}=\\
\int_{0}^{q}dx\frac{x^{2n}}{1-e^{ax}}-\int_{0}^{q}dx\frac{x^{2n}e^{ax}}{1-e^{ax}}=\\
\\\int_{0}^{q}dxx^{2n}=\frac{q^{2n+1}}{2n+1}
$$

so

$$
I_{q,n}(a)=\frac{q^{2n+1}a}{2n+1}+C
$$

but by symmetry $I(0_+)=0$ and we get

> $$
> I_{q,n}(a)=\frac{q^{2n+1}a}{2n+1}
> $$

and the actual question is answered by setting $q=1,n=1$

> $$
> I(a)=I_{1,1}(a)=\frac{a}{3}
> $$

Comment: excuse me i forgot a ''$log$''